# Calculating the probability of drawing two cards of the same suit from a deck of dual-suit cards

Tags: probability, card-games

I'm making a tabletop roleplaying game which uses a handmade deck of cards as a chance generator. All we need to know is that there are **16 cards** and **four suits**, but:

- Each card is of **two suits**;
- Six cards in the deck are of two **different** suits;
- And one card in the deck is of the **same suit twice**.

Thus, our cards look like this (with Hearts highlighted as an example):

| Card | Suits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **Hearts** and Clubs |
| 2 | **Hearts** and Spades |
| 3 | **Hearts** and Diamonds |
| 4 | **Hearts** and **Hearts** |
| 5 | Clubs and **Hearts** |
| 6 | Clubs and Spades |
| 7 | Clubs and Diamonds |
| 8 | Clubs and Clubs |
| 9 | Spades and **Hearts** |
| 10 | Spades and Spades |
| 11 | Spades and Diamonds |
| 12 | Spades and Clubs |
| 13 | Diamonds and Spades |
| 14 | Diamonds and Diamonds |
| 15 | Diamonds and **Hearts** |
| 16 | Diamonds and Clubs |

If I choose Hearts as my suit, and turn over a Hearts card, that's called a **success**. If I turn over the card with both suits as Hearts, that's ***two*** **successes**.

I need to calculate the probability of getting **at least n successes** when I draw *x* number of cards without replacement. For instance, it is quite common to need two successes and to draw three cards. The following sets of cards would all qualify:

- One Hearts card, one Hearts card, and one other card (2 successes)
- One double Hearts card and two other cards (2 successes)
- One double Hearts card, one Hearts card, and one other card (3 successes)
- Three Hearts cards (3 or 4 successes)

My knowledge of probability maths is basic at best, and I've set up what feels like quite a challenging system, so I'm getting nowhere calculating it. I'd be grateful for the specific probability of getting 2 successes on 3 cards, but a general formula for me to calculate successes would be even better!

Comment: In your example of qualifying draws, you've missed the possibility of 4 successes in 3 cards, if you draw the double Heart and two more Hearts. Also, I assume we draw without replacement here? Writing out the closed-form exact solution of no-replacement problems can be tricky since there are many branches based on the sequence of what you pick - it may be easier to do a Monte Carlo approximation and just simulate it empirically if you know a little programming.

Comment: Yes, we draw without replacement (sorry, I mention that in the question, but in the middle of a bunch of other stuff!) And yes, you're right, I'll edit that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $6$ single-Heart cards and $1$ double-Heart card, so to get at least $n$ successes in $x$ draws, we must either

- Draw at least $n$ single-Heart cards and no double-Heart card, or
- Draw the double-Heart card and get at least $n-2$ single-Heart cards in the other $x-1$ draws.

In the first case, if we are to draw $k$ single-Heart cards, there are $\binom 6k$ ways to choose them, and there are $\binom 9{x-k}$ ways to choose the remaining $x-k$ cards from among the $9$ non-Heart cards,  so there are $$\sum_{k=n}^x{\binom 6k\binom 9{x-k}}$$ ways in all.

We can do the second case in much the same way.  The double-Heart cards must be chosen, and then we have $\binom 6k\binom 9{x-1-k}$ ways to choose $k$ single-Hearts and $x-1-k$ non-Hearts, giving $$\sum_{k=n-2}^{x-1}{\binom 6k\binom 9{x-k-1}}$$

There are $\binom{16}{x}$ ways to draw $x$ cards, so the probability is
$$\frac1{\binom{16}{x}}\left(\sum_{k=n}^x{\binom 6k\binom 9{x-k}}+\sum_{k=n-2}^{x-1}{\binom 6k\binom 9{x-k-1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, it is probably easier to find the probability of drawing one or zero hearts.

So

- zero hearts: $\dfrac{9 \choose 3}{16 \choose 3}=0.15$
- one heart: $\dfrac{{6 \choose 1}{9 \choose 2}}{16 \choose 3}\approx0.386$

and then subtract both from $1$ to give $\frac{13}{28}\approx 0.464$

Comment: This was very helpful to get a quick calculation, thank you!